# MongoDb - specify the ID field from javascript script

Tags: mongodb

I'm running the following script to insert a document to mongodb (`script.js`):

```
var document = {
    MyCustomId : "12345",
    Name  : "MyResource",
    DisplayName : "Test Resource"
};

db.Resources.insert(document);
```

I'm running the following command to run it: `mongo localhost/MyDb script.js`

It create the document with the mongo `_id` field. But I want to user my own custom string field (`MyCustomId` in the example above). How can I do that?

Comment: You want to create index on 'MyCustomId' ? mongo creates _id as unique key.

Comment: `_id` is a mandatory field, but you can safely ignore it if you don't need it.

Comment: You can change your doc from `MyCustomId : "12345"`, to `_id : "12345"`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Can I somehow set _id to be of type of string?

Comment: @developer82 `_id` can be of whatever type you want.